# Bash Script as ScreenSaver

Tags: linux, bash, screensaver, linux-mint, mplayer

I am trying to create a script to use a movie as ScreenSaver, but once the movie is opened, the system freezes and reboots.

I have been pulling hairs off of my head because I cannot figure out why this happens. I tried the same script in another machine and it worked perfectly for many months...

The machine it worked on was a Linux Mint 13 machine and the one it didn't work on was a Linux Mint 17 machine.

The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen_on=false;
state=0;
time_idle=1200;

while true;do

IDLE=$(./idletime)


if [ $IDLE -gt $time_idle ];then

    if [ $(pidof mplayer) ];then

        echo "Screen is on " >> mylog.log

    else
        ./test.sh &

    fi

else
    if [ $(pidof mplayer) ];then

        pkill mplayer

    else
        echo "Screen is off." >> mylog.log

    fi

fi

done
```

The idletime program is actually the same as xprintidle... It uses the X Server to get the system's idle time.
The test.sh script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

mplayer -nostop-xscreensaver movie.mp4 -fs -loop 0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What's probably happening is a Denial of Service attack.

If you have two mplayer processes, your script starts bombing the system, starting an infinite number of mplayers as quickly as possible.

Use [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net). It would have warned you about missing quotes in `if [ $(pidof mplayer) ]`. The correct code is:

```
if [ "$(pidof mplayer)" ]
then
  echo "There is one or more mplayer processes"
else
  echo "There are no mplayer processes."
fi
```

It can be more directly written as

```
if pidof mplayer > /dev/null
then 
  ...
```

PS: You can also replace `while true` with `while sleep 1`, which will reduce the script's CPU usage from 100% to <1% with no loss of functionality.

Comment: I don't see how the script would cause that to happen but yes as soon as it did it would absolutely start spawning `mplayer` processes as fast as it possibly could. An explicit lock for this would be a much better idea.

Comment: Apart from external factors it could be a race condition when test.sh is started in the background.

Comment: True, with a while loop as greedy as that it could absolutely be racing the process spawning.